# how to get today's date + 1 day in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to get today's date but I want also to display today's date + 1 day (in this case 03/12/1013) can someone show me how to do it please?

```
function today() {
    var text = '';
    var date = new Date();
    var jour_actuel = date.getDay();
    var chaine_jour = Array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thurdays', 'friday',
    'saturday');
    var jour_semaine = chaine_jour[jour_actuel];
    if (date.getDate() <= 9) { var jour = '0' + date.getDate(); }
    else { var jour = date.getDate(); }
    var mois_actuel = date.getMonth();
    var chaine_mois = Array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12');
    var mois = chaine_mois[mois_actuel];
    text +=jour + '/' + mois + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('today').innerHTML = text; 
} setInterval('today()', 1000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answer when you have the time. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`var myDate = new Date();`

`myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);`

`console.log(myDate);`

Right now this outputs:

*Tue Dec 03 2013 10:19:36 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)*